# JQuery asynchronous image slideshow preloading

Tags: jquery, asynchronous, callback, promise

I am writing a script using a JQuery animation framework. In this scenario I need to have a sequence of different animations. When a new animation starts, I need to change the background image of the page.

The animation framework (it's called JSTween) provides the following callbacks:

```
onStart: function () {},
onStop: function () {}
```

I'm looking for a JQuery implementation for the following pseudocode:

```
onStart: function () {
    load new background;
}

onStop: function () {
    // This animation has ended, about four seconds have passed
    on new background loaded: {
       // Change background
    }

    // Start new animation async
}
```

I've been looking for `$.when` and similar tools, but I cannot figure out how to use them correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement a couple functions that act like `$.when`. Basically you register a function that is run in the runtime context of the `onStart` function:

```
var background_callback;

var loadNewBackground = function() {
  background_callback();
}

var onBackgroundLoaded = function (callback) {
  background_callback = callback;
}
```

Your code **edited** will be:

```
onStart: function () {
    // load new background;
    loadNewBackground();
}

onStop: function () {
    // This animation has ended, about four seconds have passed
    onBackgroundLoaded(function() {
       // Change background
    });

    // Start new animation async
}
```